# VirtualHost Redirect should work with new RewriteBase

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-2.4, rewritecond

Inside the **VirtualHost** I got this redirect:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

So the full VirtualHost config is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost.foo

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /home/me/public_html/foo

        LogLevel info

        ErrorLog /home/me/public_html/foo/error.log
        CustomLog /home/me/public_html/foo/access.log combined

    <Directory "/home/me/public_html/foo">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All

        RewriteBase /
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-content/uploads/([^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png))$
        RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But in a subfolder I got a **`.htaccess` changing the RewriteBase**:

```
RewriteBase /thisIsMe
```

Now when I access an image

- `http://localhost.foo/thisIsMe/wp-content/uploads/someImage.jpg`
- **Should redirect to:** `http://example.org/thisIsMe/wp-content/uploads/someImage.jpg`
- but redirects to `http://example.org/wp-content/uploads/someImage.jpg`

So the `RewriteBase /thisIsMe` in the URL got lost.

How can I achieve the correct URL as above?

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteBase` is used for per-directory rewrites, i.e. rewrites with a relative path to/from the directory. Your rewrite contains an **absolute** path since it points to an entirely different hostname. (It may be on the same host, but mod_rewrite doesn't know that...).

Instead of using `RewriteBase`, you should add the actual path that you want to have inserted - e.g.:

```
    RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/ThisIsMe/$1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks. I can do that and it's my current workaround. But I like to have the rule for all sub-directories so placing the name there would mean that the sub-folder "thatIsAnother" would point to "http://example.org/ThisIsMe" instead of "http://example.org/thatIsAnother".

Comment: From the information in the question, the captured URL-path (`$1` backreference) should already contain the full URL-path starting `thisIsMe/...`, so there would seem to be something else going on here. It is quite likely the OP is using mod_rewrite inheritance to inherit the parent directives into `/thisIsMe/.htaccess` - this would account for the missing `thisIsMe/` directory in the captured URL-path. In which case they would need to use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead. I've added an answer with more explantion... https://serverfault.com/a/1032180/49157

Answer (score 0):

As @JennyD already stated in her answer, the `RewriteBase` directive does not apply when using absolute URL *substitution* strings in the `RewriteRule` directive.

However, the directives as posted should already work as intended (`RewriteBase` is not requried). The captured backreference (`$1`) should already contain the full URL-path. ie. `thisIsMe/wp-content/uploads/someImage.jpg`.

Unless... in your `/thisIsMe/.htaccess` file you are using mod_rewrite inheritance to inherit the `<Directory>` mod_rewrite directives in-place in the `.htaccess` file. This would seem quite likely, given you are trying to set `RewriteBase` here. Since the mod_rewrite directives are effectively copied in-place (inherited) in the subdirectory's `.htaccess` file, you will lose the subdirectory from the captured backreference.

To resolve this you could either:

- Remove the mod_rewrite directives entirely from the `/thisIsMe/.htaccess` file - not necessarily practical if you have other/specific mod_rewrite directives here (although these can always be moved to the server config). The mod_rewrite directives in the `<Directory>` container are then simply processed as-is, they are not "inherited" into a child config.

OR,

- Use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable instead in the inherited directives in the `<Directory>` container. `REQUEST_URI` always contains the full URL-path (starting with a slash). So, will naturally contain the `/thisIsMe` prefix. For example:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/[^.]+\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  ```

  The preceding `RewriteCond` (and `RewriteBase`) directive(s) are not required. The `RewriteEngine On` directive is required - unless this is already enabled earlier in the config.